# how can we find all empty input fields in a div

Tags: jquery

how can we find empty select drop down and input field as below, where all fields can be declared in single parameter and do validation in particular division.

```js
$("div").find("input[type=radio]:checked, input[type=checkbox]:checked").size() === 0;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Do you mean `un-checked`?

Comment: `input:not(:checked)`

Comment: nope, empty input text fields and select dropdown

Comment: Also, `size()` was deprecated many years ago, use `.length` https://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: *"empty text fields and select"* then why does your sample have checkboxes and radios?

Comment: You can't do it with a selector, but you can with filter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844770/find-empty-input-elements-inside-a-collection-jquery and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21410484/jquery-selector-to-find-out-count-of-non-empty-inputs (and probably others)

Comment: in a div i have all input types i just want to alert if no filed is selected or empty or checked. if any one field selected i will just move to another div

Answer (score 3):

Use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method for that.

```
$("div").find("select,:text").filter(function() {
  return !$(this).val().trim().length;
}).length
```